# firebase deploy command for Node.js application results in Error: `runtime` field is required but was not found in firebase.json

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am trying to deploy my Node.js application in firebase but when I run the command it results in the error `Error:` runtime `field is required but was not found in firebase.json.`

[image]

I tried running the command `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` and everything works fine locally so I would like to deploy and provide the link to my colleagues for the user testing but I am unable to do it using the `firebase deploy` command.

I tried adding the command to my `firebase.json` file but still no luck. Here is my original `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After getting the error I changed to this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "runtime": "nodejs10",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Still getting the error, I am bit confused where exactly I need to add the command `"runtime": "nodejs10",`. I tried looking but could not find any relevant article on the similar issue, can anyone please help me.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message says to add it to the "**functions**" section.  You're adding it to the "hosting" section, which won't work.  The runtime choice is made for Cloud Functions, not Firebase Hosting.  They are different products with different configuration.

The message is also not entirely accurate about what to add.

Add the runtime to the functions section as discussed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version):

```
{
  "functions": {
    "engines": {"node": "10"}
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation says to put `"engines": ...` into the **`package.json`** of your functions project. **Alternatively** you can add `{"functions
"{"runtime": "nodejs14"}}` to your `firebase.json`, though this isn't mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To set the runtime ,set the version in the `engines` field in the package.json file that was created in your functions/ directory during initialization. For example, to use only version 10, edit this line in package.json:

`"engines":{"node":"10"}`

The engines field is required; it must specify one of the supported Node.js versions in order for you to deploy and run functions. Currently, firebase init functions sets this field to  node 10